# What are the natural, synthetic, identical, heterogeneous qubits? Can anyone explain with examples?

Tags: experimental-realization, research

I am reading [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05207) from 2016, "Quantum computing with atomic qubits and
Rydberg interactions: Progress and challenges",

In section 2.1, a debate on whether identical or heterogeneous qubits work better for large scale systems. I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between the identical and the heterogeneous qubits?
2. Is there a result for the debate above?

Thanks for any help!